# Can't figure out why jsLint throws unescaped '[' in regex

Tags: javascript, regex, jslint

This is my function,

```
function validateEmail(email) { 
var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
return re.test(email);
```

}

JsLint Throws **unescaped '['** in re declaration ! is there anything wrong with the construction of regex ?

Comment: i've tried your code on google chrome console for these data and no problems where occured:

`re.test("name@domain.com");`
`re.test("mas@domainfortest");`
`re.test("mas@dom a.cs");`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first part of your regex (`[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+`), you may need to escape the inner `[`:

```
[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+
       ^
```

This must be done in the next part of your regex as well.

Comment: Ya, Simple one.Thanks.